# Редактирование JS в браузере

Tags: javascript

Имеется страница, которая содержит в себе js-код. При открытии редактора в браузере невозможно изменить какие-либо значения. Просто не дает редактировать.
Каким образом можно отредактировать код?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте окно консоли браузера. В консоли можно менять значения переменных. Установите прерывание на нужной строке и после остановки - меняйте. В принципе таким образом можно менять и код - заменив функцию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если ты хочешь редактировать файл прям в браузере то тебе нужно сначало зайти в закладку `Sources`, далее под `Sources` выбрать закладку ниже `Overrides` или `Filesystem` и дать права браузеру на использование диска, и указать файл перезаписи или папку проекта.

Далее зайти в настройке babel или чем ты там пользуешься и включить SourceMaps. Тогда браузер сможет определить что `кашица.min.js` это вовсе не кашица, а реальный файл `my-app.js` из папки проекта.

https://babeljs.io/docs/options#source-map-options

Да будет тебе счастье! )